# Function definition with an ellipsis

Tags: c, function, language-lawyer, ellipsis

I have misunderstanding about the semantic of functions with variable number of arguments. `6.5.2.2(p6)`:

> If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype,
>   and either  the  prototype  ends  with  an  ellipsis  (, ...)  or  the 
>   types  of  the  arguments  after promotion are not compatible with the
>   types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.

This is not really clear. Does in the function definition below the prototype end with an ellipsis?

```
void foo(int i, ...){
    //...
}
```

At first I thought that it was about the function the parameter list contains the ellipsis only, like

```
void foo(...){
    //...
}
```

but this case is described by `6.9.1(p8)`:

> If a function that accepts a variable number of arguments is defined
>   without a parameter type list that ends with the ellipsis notation, the
>   behavior is undefined

So I don't really understand what did they mean by

> either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...)

at `6.5.2.2(p6)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This paragraph discusses the case where a function call expression mentions a function for which no prototype has been seen. In this case, the compiler has to guess at the types of its parameters, based on types of arguments of the call.

If that function is defined (possibly in a different translation unit) as variadic, or with parameter types that don't match the compiler's guess, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: _This paragraph discusses the case where a function call expression mentions a function for which no prototype has been seen_ Could you please expand on this? they mentioned that _**If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype**, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...)_. Can you suggest an example of UB specified at `6.5.2.2(p6)`?

Comment: It's defined *somewhere*, but not where its prototype can be seen by this particular call expression. For example, in a different source file. For historical reasons, C allows calling functions out of the blue, without ever seeing its declaration. So you can write `int main() { return f(1, 2); }`, and the compiler crosses its figurative fingers and hopes that somewhere maybe there's a definition of `int f(int, int)`. If instead you define, in a different source file, `int f(double, double)` or `int f(int, ...)`, the behavior of that call is undefined.

Comment: So the function is declared without prototype and the declaration is seen (the quote: _If  the  expression  that  denotes  the  called  function  has  a  type  that  does  not  include a prototype_). But the definition is not in the scope and is provided at link time. Is that what they were trying to say?

Comment: @SomeName The historical reasons also allow you to declare a function without prototypes too, e.g. `int f();` in a header file will match both the expected `int f(int, int)` and the actual `int f(double, double)` definitions.

Comment: "This paragraph discusses the case where a function call expression mentions a function for which no prototype has been seen" is good, yet the paragraph also applies to the case  where the function is prototyped with a `...`